# Odoo/OpenERP - custom module's export links visibility in tree, list view

Tags: excel, odoo, odoo-8

I have installed module web_printscreen_zb in my Odoo v8 system. The module shows correctly "Pdf" and "Excel" links at the top of the page if the view is of type "list". However, if the view is of type "tree", those two links are not visible. I have tried to hack the module's "web_printscreen_export.xml" file by changing active_view from "list" to "tree" but with no results, the links are still not shown.

What I need to do to be able to show "Pdf" and "Excel" links for the view of type "tree"? Concrete example is "Bill of Materials" list view (model "mrp.bom"), links visible, and "Bill of Materials Structure" tree view (model "mrp.bom.line"), links are not visible. Please see attached pictures. There is a difference between list and tree view.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think that you cant.. why u dont change te view_type of bill of materials to  form type so you can export it?

Comment: @DanielCrocco    It's a good idea and I have tried that, however BOM Structure items are hierarchical (parent-child), they are expanded, and view type = form just shows list of items and not the expanding parent-child items. If I can get hierarchical list (if something like that exist) then I will be able to show buttons and export.